# Количество локальных переменных

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли средствами JavaScript получить полный список локальных переменных в зоне видимости определённой функции?

Comment: Список должен быть получен изнутри функции, или снаружи ?

Comment: `var a; function x(){var b, c;}` какие переменные должны стать результатом из a, b, c ?

Comment: Список должен быть получен изнутри функции.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что нельзя. Однако, в браузере в инструментах разработчика можно увидеть скоуп, принадлежащий функции.

И ещё. Если в функции не используются `debugger`, `with` и `eval` (а также, некоторые другие штуки), и оптимизатор способен определить, что используется в функции, а что нет, то он выкинет неиспользуемые переменные из замыкания.

Напоминаю, что в стандарте говорится о сохранении всех переменных, но с оговоркой, что браузер имеет право поступать по-другому, если для исполняемого кода разница не заметна. Могу точно сказать, что Хром (точнее, v8) выкидывает лишние переменные.